# electric P.E. of a point charge

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

Referring to electrostatics, as a test charge $+q$ moves opposite to an electric field, will its electric potential energy increase or decrease? Some textbooks show it increasing and some say the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link between electrostatic field and potential is

$$ \mathbf{E} = -\nabla V$$

so $\mathbf{E}$ is goes where $V$ is the lower. Then, since $E_p = qV$, if $q > 0$, when the charge is moving opposite to the electric field, $E_p$ incease, else it decreases.

Physically, potential energy corresponds to the energy the charge is *storing* and which can be transformed to kinetic energy. Thus, you can predict that displacing a positive charge against the electric field will increase its potential energy: indeed, when you release the charge, the further you've moved it, the faster it will be.

Comment: You were quicker.

Comment: Thanks... Your equational logic satisfied me but your physical logic make confusion ..make it understandable .... Thanks ..!